# How to pass DateTime value parameter?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a function that have parameter for `DateTime`

```
   AddNewRowToTable(....,DateTime ExpDate)
```

when I call that method like this below:

```
   AddNewRowToTable(....,"2008/04/14")
```

It said it can't convert `string` to `DateTime`.

help!

Comment: try `New DateTime(year, month, day)` instead of `2008/04/14`

Comment: what is `AddNewRow`? can you update the question with code?

Comment: `AddNewRow` and `AddNewRowToTable` are not the same. Correct the question please. Also you can not pass a different type unless some kind of function overloading is implemented by you for your function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
You have to do AddNewRow(....,new DateTime(..))
```

or `AddNewRow(....,DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider))`

There is no implicit conversion from string

Answer (score 4):

You will have to convert the `string` to type `DateTime`. You can convert it in this way:

```
AddNewRow(....,new DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08", "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass correct type for the input parameter. Look into function overloading if you want to pass a `String` and then convert it into `DateTime` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little to the previous answers new DateTime() it appears to expect a long.

So it has to be divided by ","  as such:

```
AddNewRowToTable(....,new DateTime(2008,04,14))
```